# SQL query to generate this output

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I've got this table in Oracle (Top 3 rows are):

```
ID               StartTime                  EndTime
AAAAAA     20-Sep-2009 11:08:00       21-Sep-2009 12:08:54
BBBBBB     20-Sep-2009 02:08:33       21-Sep-2009 12:08:58
CCCCCC     20-Sep-2009 10:08:34       21-Sep-2009 12:08:38
```

I'm trying to "generate" a trigger for each ID in a SELECT query, so I have to write 1 for the StartTime and 0 to the EndTime. The result I'm looking for would be:

```
Timestamp               Trigger_ID     ID
20-Sep-2009 11:08:00    1            AAAAAA 
20-Sep-2009 02:08:33    1            BBBBBB 
20-Sep-2009 10:08:34    1            CCCCCC
21-Sep-2009 12:08:54    0            AAAAAA 
21-Sep-2009 12:08:58    0            BBBBBB 
21-Sep-2009 12:08:38    0            CCCCCC
```

[Apologies for the formatting issues]

I think I have to do something like:

```
SELECT StartTime, '0' as Trigger_ID, ID From MyTable

SELECT EndTime, '1' as Trigger_ID, ID From MyTable
```

Bu I don't now how to merge these outputs in a single output.

Can someone help me with this query?

Many thanks in advance! :D

Comment: What have you tried so far? We won't write code for you, but we can help you debug yours.

Comment: Edited with my code so far. I'm sorry I haven't done it before...my code so far is a bit stupid I suppose :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use `UNION ALL`:

```
select starttime timestamp, 1 trigger_id, id
from yourtable
union all
select endtime, 0, id
from yourtable
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e716f/2)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using 11g and above:

```
with tab(ID,StartTime,EndTime) as
(select 'AAAAAA', '20-Sep-2009 11:08:00', '21-Sep-2009 12:08:54' from dual union all
 select 'BBBBBB', '20-Sep-2009 02:08:33', '21-Sep-2009 12:08:58' from dual union all
 select 'CCCCCC', '20-Sep-2009 10:08:34', '21-Sep-2009 12:08:38' from dual)
--------------
--End of Data
--------------
select timestamp,  trigger_id, id
  from tab
unpivot (timestamp for trigger_id in (StartTime as '1', EndTime as '0'));
```

Output:

```
|            TIMESTAMP | TRIGGER_ID |     ID |
|----------------------|------------|--------|
| 20-Sep-2009 11:08:00 |          1 | AAAAAA |
| 21-Sep-2009 12:08:54 |          0 | AAAAAA |
| 20-Sep-2009 02:08:33 |          1 | BBBBBB |
| 21-Sep-2009 12:08:58 |          0 | BBBBBB |
| 20-Sep-2009 10:08:34 |          1 | CCCCCC |
| 21-Sep-2009 12:08:38 |          0 | CCCCCC |
```